# Laravel 5.3 add html to MailMessage->line

Tags: php, html, laravel, email, laravel-5

I like to add some html tags to the body of my mail using MailMessage like this:

```
$mailMessage = new MailMessage();
$mailMessage->line(trans('mail.someLine') );
```

In mail.php:

```
'someLine' => 'Bla bla <a href="html://someurl">html://someurl</a>'
```

But in the actual mail the entire line comes out as plain text.

I've tried to use `html_entity_decode` but without any success:

```
 $mailMessage->line(html_entity_decode(trans('mail.someLine')));
```

Seems like the line method does it's own encoding. Is there a workaround for this?

ps The rest of the mail has proper html so that's not the point!

update:
$mailMessage->action won't do in this case. Let say it should work for something like this as well:
`$mailMessage->line('Bla bla <strong>something strong</strong> bla');`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Checking the MailMessage/SimpleMessage code I found it was not these classes that did the encoding but the email.blade.php template itself.

Changing the `{{ $line }}` parts into  `{!! $line !!}` in the email.blade.php eventually did the trick.

ps Make sure to run `php artisan vendor:publish` first so you don't need to change the original email.blade.php in the vendor folder!

Answer (score 50):

Better to use `HtmlString` class.

```
use Illuminate\Support\HtmlString;

return (new MailMessage)
  ->line(new HtmlString($someHtmlBody));
```

Line will be show as processed HTML code.

Comment: Works perfectly - just a note be aware this HTML is not escaped so don't include user input in here unless you know it's safe.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the line function is not supposed to contain html. If you want to pass an URL you should use the action function. You might also want to customize your mail template.
Check the official docs about the mail notifications:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/notifications#mail-notifications

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in `Mail/resources/html/layout.blade.php`, Laravel uses the Markdown notation:

`{{ Illuminate\Mail\Markdown::parse($slot) }}`

So you can format your strings (even insert images) using a code like this:

`$mailMessage->line('Bla bla **something strong** bla');`

> Bla bla **something strong** bla

Comment: Using laravel 10, this is still the current behavior

Answer (score 0):

try by adding action tag with MailMesage object.

```
 $mailMessage
        ->line('Simple mail')
        ->action('Link Title', url('password/reset', $this->token));
```

Comment: Problem is that action will show a button (which I also need in the same template, so I can't change the tamplate for that matter).
How about if I wanted a word in a strong-tag for example?

Comment: you can override $mailMessage->view() to define your custom view for notification.

Comment: I found the best solution for the specific issue was to change the email.blade, but overriding would also have been an option!